# Tomcat - How to block access to specific folder\pages

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have the following app structure.

```
webapps
   |
   ->MyApp
       |
       ->index1.html
       ->index2.html
       ->index3.html
       ->someFolder
```

Is it possible to block access to specific pages folder ?  In this case "someFolder" so no one could access it ?
And to allow access only the index files ?

I was able to find solutions which include IP blocking but I want to block it to all without configure IP list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<security-constraint>` in your `web.xml` that requires a user-role to which no users belong.

Or, if you can re-locate the files, put those files under `/WEB-INF` and Tomcat will prohibit direct-access to these files (though servlets can successfully forward requests to resources within `/WEB-INF` using a request dispatcher).

Comment: If I'll define the <security-constraint> , the index files will be able to load pages and files from the "someFolder" ?

Comment: If `index.html` is a plain-old static file, then the only way it can include things is with references like `<img src="someFolder/somefile.jpg" />`, etc. If the browser can request the resource, then any remote client can access it. If you explain your requirements a little better, I can give you a better answer.

Comment: I have Angular app with same structure as above less or more. I need to block any option to access to any of the files which in the "someFolder" (html , js ..) and to allow access to only the index files . since this is angular app , the index files  import JS files and show views which are part of the "someFolder"  you think the solution you provided can work in this case ?

Comment: There is no solution which meets your requirements. You need to re-think how to package your application. For example, you could move all your "private" assets into a folder that is not accessible at all (I recommend under `/WEB-INF`) and then write a servlet or JSP which will assemble them into the final product given a public URL that *is* accessible from the outside.